# Excel check if cell contains text from list and return value from list

Tags: excel

I've seen many posts about the subject, but in general the question has been to return the value of a cell if the cell contains text from a list. I have used the following formula for that:

```
=IF(OR(INDEX(COUNTIF(Cell;"*"&Array&"*");));1;0)
```

However, what I want is to check if a cell contains text from a list, and if this is TRUE then show the text from the list, not the cell. A small example below.

In column A I have the following values

```
abc123
def123
ghi123
jkl123
```

In column B (the list)

```
abc
def
jkl
```

Now the first cell (abc123) is in the list, i want to show the text from the list (abc) in the formula cell.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following array formulas:

- If the text you are searching is always placed at the beginning of the string

  `{=INDEX($B$1:$B$3;MATCH(1;SEARCH(TRANSPOSE($B$1:$B$3);A1);0);0)}`
- or if the text you are searching is placed anywhere

  `{=INDEX($B$1:$B$3;MATCH(1;--(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE($B$1:$B$3);A1)>0);0);0)}`

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]